# Combining individual select aggregate queries into a single query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to optimise some SQL queries in a script of mine that uses a SQLite database. Currently I loop through creating multiple queries as below to get aggregate data for a list of IP addresses. Is there a way to run this as one query instead? Desired output is the "top 20 domains" for each IP.

```
SELECT ipaddr, domain, Count(domain) Count
FROM tablea
WHERE (ipaddr = 'IP')
GROUP BY domain
ORDER BY COUNT(domain) DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Current results, with 1 query run per IP. I'd like to combine these into 1 query if possible.

```
IP1|DOMAIN1|COUNT
IP1|DOMAIN2|COUNT
IP2|DOMAIN3|COUNT
IP2|DOMAIN4|COUNT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must group by `ipaddr` and `domain` and use `ROW_NUMBER()` (or `RANK()`) window function to rank the the domains:

```
SELECT ipaddr, domain, Count
FROM (
  SELECT ipaddr, domain, COUNT(*) Count,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ipaddr ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rn
  FROM tablea
  WHERE ipaddr IN ('IP1', 'IP2', 'IP3', ...)
  GROUP BY ipaddr, domain
)
WHERE rn <= 20 
ORDER BY ipaddr, Count DESC
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but I seem to only get 1 result e.g. 
10.14.16.40|www.google.com|6109
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @jackyaz with the code in my answer you should get 1-20 rows for each combination of ipaddr and domain. If you only get 1 row then this means that you did not use it exactly as it is or your data is not as you described. Post sample data here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27 to reproduc your issue.

Comment: Just spotted my mistake when substituting in the field names, working now! Thank you very much!